# Implementing a Binary Heap data structure using C# that can take in Generic Types and Insert/Sort via Value Property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to Merge K Sorted Linked Lists using a MinHeap binary heap structure. I currently have a proper Min/MaxHeap implementation in C# that I used for coding challenges, but it only takes in a type of integers.

What sort of implementation can I use for C# if I want to use a MinHeap which heapifies based on a ListNode's int Value property?

I've looked everywhere for a working PriorityQueue or Binary Heap C# implementation to use during coding interviews, but I have yet to find one that properly takes in Generic Types and can be sorted via a property (perhaps with IComparable?)

For the Java implementation of what I'm describing, I've provided the example below:

```
import java.util.*;

class ListNode {
  int value;
  ListNode next;

  ListNode(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class MergeKSortedLists {

  public static ListNode merge(ListNode[] lists) {
    PriorityQueue<ListNode> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>((n1, n2) -> n1.value - n2.value);

    // put the root of each list in the min heap
    for (ListNode root : lists)
      if (root != null)
        minHeap.add(root);

    // take the smallest (top) element form the min-heap and add it to the result; 
    // if the top element has a next element add it to the heap
    ListNode resultHead = null, resultTail = null;
    while (!minHeap.isEmpty()) {
      ListNode node = minHeap.poll();
      if (resultHead == null) {
        resultHead = resultTail = node;
      } else {
        resultTail.next = node;
        resultTail = resultTail.next;
      }
      if (node.next != null)
        minHeap.add(node.next);
    }

    return resultHead;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode l1 = new ListNode(2);
    l1.next = new ListNode(6);
    l1.next.next = new ListNode(8);

    ListNode l2 = new ListNode(3);
    l2.next = new ListNode(6);
    l2.next.next = new ListNode(7);

    ListNode l3 = new ListNode(1);
    l3.next = new ListNode(3);
    l3.next.next = new ListNode(4);

    ListNode result = MergeKSortedLists.merge(new ListNode[] { l1, l2, l3 });
    System.out.print("Here are the elements form the merged list: ");
    while (result != null) {
      System.out.print(result.value + " ");
      result = result.next;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should share your "proper min/maxheap implementation in C#" so we can see what your problem is

Comment: Hi @ElFik thanks for your response! Here is the Min/MaxHeap I'm currently using for coding challenges that require a binary heap with integers: https://gist.github.com/WuchiOnline/e33bfa15f4110e806f501bebdb792450